# How do I grep for occurences of "[numberLargerThan5000]ms"?

Tags: grep, logs, numeric-data

I have a .log file where each entry is on the form

```
2018-09-28T10:53:48,006 [Jetty-6152  ] INFO  [correlationId] my.package.service:570 - Inbound request: 1.2.3.4 - GET - 12342ms - 200 - /json/some/resource
2018-09-28T11:53:48,006 [Jetty-6152  ] INFO  [correlationId] my.package.service:570 - Inbound request: 1.2.3.4 - GET - 204ms - 200 - /json/other/resource
```

How do I find all entries where the request took longer than 5 seconds? that is the entry contains the text "[numberGreaterThan5000]ms"?

Comment: If you have tried something you should post the code that you tried and how it failed as well.  So we can see that you did some work for yourself first and also can help you improve that code. (I posted a quick reply anyway.)

Comment: Could you please clarify the question. How you want to find: `that is the entry contains the text "[numberGreaterThan5000]ms"`?  this statement is ` "[numberGreaterThan5000]ms"` not in your example?

Comment: @TNT the sentence before that should explain it very well. They try to find any line where that number before the string "ms" is greater than 5000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
grep -E '([5-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5,})ms' | grep -v 5000ms
```

How does it work?

1. It uses `-E` so the regex is of the "modern" format (also called extended).  It just makes the typing easier in our case as we can save some `\` chars.
2. The `(...|...)ms` searches for two alternatives followed by the string `ms`.  This is necessary as regex can not compare numbers so I can not say something like  `>= 5000`.
3. The first alternative is `[5-9][0-9]{3}` which will match any string that starts with a number from 5 to 9 followed by 3 occurrences of numbers from 0 to 9.  Those are all numbers >= 5000 and < 10000.
4. The second alternative will match a string of 5 or more digits, that is any number >= 10000.
5. At the end we pipe the result to `grep -v 5000ms` to filter out any occurrence of `5000ms` because you said **greater** than 5000. If you want greater or equal just leave that out.

Where to learn more?

Read `man 1 grep` and `man 7 regex`.

Comment: Downvoters: care to explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should avoid trying to build numeric comparisons out of regular expressions - use something like `awk` or `perl` that can do actual numeric comparisons e.g.

```
gawk -v x=5000 'match($0,/([0-9]+)ms/,a) && a[1]+0 > x' file.log
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print if /(\d+)ms/ && $1 > 5000' file.log
```